# WLAN stick not working at boot time

Tags: wifi, network-interface, usb-device, dhclient

I am failing to use a *FRITZ!WLAN USB Stick N* to connect my Raspberry Pi 1B to my wireless network. I see several problems, but am unable to locate and eliminate the root cause. The problem is reproducible on a Raspberyy Pi 3B.

At the end of the boot process, the wireless network is not available, the network device is shown by `ifconfig`, but without IP address. `iwconfig` reports

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

### Manual Fix (works)

If I bring wlan0 up manually with `ifup wlan0`, everything works just fine and the machine connects to my network (trying to leave out hopefully irrelevant stuff):

```
wpa_supplicant[854]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.1
dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
wpa_supplicant[855]: wlan0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wpa_supplicant[855]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
[...]
wpa_supplicant[855]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx completed [id=0 id_str=]
dhcpcd[485]: wlan0: carrier acquired
wpa_supplicant[855]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
dhcpcd[485]: wlan0: adding address xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
dhcpcd[485]: wlan0: IAID 43:0d:1f:fd
dhcpcd[485]: wlan0: rebinding lease of xxx.xxx.x.xx
dhcpcd[485]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
dhclient: bound to xxx.xxx.x.xx -- renewal in 335050 seconds.
```

However, I would like to let the (headless) system boot and connect unsupervised.

### Hypothesis

Maybe the problem is that the USB stick changes its USB ID after loading its firmware?

*syslog* tells me that the stick is recognized early in the boot process (t=4.2s) having idVendor=057c and idProduct=**84ff**. Right after that (t=5.3s), a SCSI CD-ROM with the label "FRITZ! WLAN selfinstall 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS" is detected. I guess that the stick itself provides that drive to let the machine load some USB chip firmware.

At some point between t=12s and t=15.5s, _wpa_supplicant_ tries to bring up the networking device but fails:

```
wpa_supplicant[264]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wpa_supplicant[264]: Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device 
wpa_supplicant[264]: nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands 
wpa_supplicant[264]: Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device 
wpa_supplicant[264]: WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP 
wpa_supplicant[264]: wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface networking[198]: Configuring network interfaces...wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start 
networking[198]: run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1 
networking[198]: Failed to bring up wlan0.
networking[198]: done.
```

Much later (t=30s) the USB device disconnects and reconnects showing idVendor=057c, idProduct=**8401**. Soon after (t=34.2s), *dhcpcd* tries again but fails to connect to the network:

```
dhcpcd[484]: wlan0: adding address xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
dhcpcd[484]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
kernel: [   35.199371] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
khcpcd[484]: wlan0: carrier acquired
dhcpcd[484]: wlan0: IAID 43:0d:1f:fd
dhcpcd[484]: wlan0: carrier lost
dhcpcd[484]: wlan0: deleting address xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
```

Why does it fail? I fail to come up with a proper idea.

### Sitting it out (does not work)

Tried to set up my fallback solution: let `ifup wlan0` being called as *systemd* service. Created /etc/systemd/system/fritz.wlan.service to start a shell script as late as possible:

```
[Unit]
Description=Fritz WLAN Stick N
After=ntp.target multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/fritz.wlan.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and a shell script /usr/local/bin/fritz.wlan.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/sleep 660
iwconfig 2>&1 | grep ESSID:\"xxx > /dev/null || ifup wlan0 2>&1 >> /var/log/fritz.wlan.log
```

This leads to no success. The script is started right after multi-user.target. *syslog* tells me that the device was brought up and a DHCP lease was acquired, but soon after, the kernel decides to deauthenticate the device which unwinds the whole connection:

```
kernel: [  717.685006] wlan0: deauthenticating from e0:28:6d:37:3e:f5 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
dhcpcd[465]: wlan0: carrier lost
wpa_supplicant[1330]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=e0:28:6d:37:3e:f5 reason=3 locally_generated=1
```

Hrmph. Later, *systemd* states that the initialization process finished. Not earlier. Well, however.

```
systemd[1]: Started Fritz WLAN Stick N.
systemd[1]: Startup finished in 3.332s (kernel) + 11min 54.388s (userspace) = 11min 57.720s.
```

Can it be that the problem comes up when `ifup wlan0` is started by *systemd* and not by an interactive root shell?

### Hacky (but working) Fallback

*cron* creates /var/run/fritz.wlan at reboot time. Another cron job lets a shell script check the existance of this file every minute. To always have a minute delay, this script touches /var/run.fritz.wlan.2 and removes the first file and exits. When being called next minute with the second file existing, the script calls `ifup wlan0`, removes the second file and exits.

Improvement would be to even remove the cron job which fires the script every minute.

Still, I would like to fully understand the problem and find a proper solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably a race condition...wpasupplicant going up too soon. As for the ID changing, I would not be surprised, 3G/4G sticks also are by default memory sticks and have to be switched to modem mode.